# Limit of $xe^{-x^2} \int_0^xe^{t^2} dt$ when $x\to\infty$

Tags: limits, definite-integrals

> Compute the limit of $xe^{-x^2} \int_0^xe^{t^2} dt$ when $x\to\infty$.

I'm not really sure how to do this attempt:

$$\lim_{x\to\infty} \left( \frac{x \int_{0}^{x}e^{x^2}dx}{e^{x^2}}\right)$$

$$=\lim_{x\to\infty} \left( \frac{ \int_{0}^{x}e^{x^2}dx + xe^{x^2}}{2xe^{x^2}} \right) \text{ By L-hopital}$$

$$=\lim_{x\to\infty} \left(\frac{\int_{0}^{x} e^{x^2} dx}{2xe^{x^2}} \right) + \frac{1}{2}$$

$$=\lim_{x\to\infty} \left(\frac{x^2}{e^{x^2}(2 + 4x^2)} \right) + \frac{1}{2} = 0 + \frac{1}{2} = \frac{1}{2}$$

Is that right?

Comment: Please avoid $\int_0^xe^{x^2} dx$ when what you mean is $\int_0^xe^{t^2} dt$. I corrected the title and the first occurrence in the body but not the other ones.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The result is right, but there is a mistake at the penultimate line, we rather have
$$
\lim_{x\to\infty} \left(\frac{\int_{0}^{x} e^{t^2} dt}{2xe^{x^2}} \right) + \frac{1}{2}=\lim_{x\to\infty} \left(\frac{\color{blue}{e^{x^2}}}{2\:\color{blue}{e^{x^2}} \left(2x^2+1\right)} \right) + \frac{1}{2}=0+\frac12=\frac12.
$$

Answer (score 2):

You can also avoid using l'Hospital's rule twice, if you make sure the derivative hits the integral:
$$ \frac{\left( \int_0^{x} e^{t^2} dt \right)'}{\left( x^{-1}e^{x^2} \right)'} = \frac{e^{x^2}}{x^{-1} \cdot 2x e^{x^2} - x^{-2} \cdot e^{x^2}} = \frac{1}{2-x^{-2}} \xrightarrow{x \to \infty} \frac{1}{2} $$